# How do I search and replace text containing placeholder tokens with a values from an xml file using regular expression matching. VB.net or C#

Tags: c#, regex, xml, vb.net

I have a problem that requires vb.net or C# solution with regular expressions matching.
I am not very good with regular expressions and so I thought I would ask for some help.
I have some text that has one or more tokens that I need to replace with values retrieved from an xml file. Tokens are similar but are of 2 different types. For matches of the first type I will replace with a value from file1.xml and for matches of the 2nd type from file2.xml.

The replaceable tokens are in this format:

Type 1 Tokens: **&*T1&** and **&*T1001&**

Type 2 Tokens: **&*SomeValue&** and **&*A2ndValue&**

The replacement values for the Type 1 tokens are in File1.xml and for Type 2 Tokens are in File2.xml

In the above example, when a match is found for Type 1 (T1000), I need to replace the entire token (&*T1000&) with the value of Element T1000 in File1.xml. `<T1000>ValueT1000</T1000>`

In the 2nd Type: When a match is found for Type 2 (SomeValue), I need to replace the entire token (&*SomeValue&) with the value of Element SomeValue in File2.xml. `<SomeValue>Value2</SomeValue>`

Example input text:
**This is some text with first token `&T1&` and the second token `&*T1001&` and more tokens `&*SomeValue&` and still more `&*A2ndValue&`.**

So far with help of the code from pirs, in vb.net, I have this:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim pattern As String = "\&\*?([\w]+)\&"
    Dim input As String = "This is some text with first token &*T1& and the second token &*T1001& and more tokens &*SomeValue& and still more &*A2ndValue&."
        For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Groups(1).Value, m.Index)
        Next
End Sub
```

Which returns:

```
'T1' found at index 35.
'T1001' found at index 62.
'SomeValue' found at index 87.
'A2ndValue' found at index 115
```

I need to process this text and replace all the tokens with their values retrieved from the 2 xml files. 
Any help is appreciated.

**[EDIT]**
With answer from @pirs. Maybe the way to do it is to first find matches of type T1000 and then replace by regex index of match. When replacing by index, I think I have to start at last index since each replace will change the index of matches.
After all T1000 matches are replaced I think I can do another match on the output string from the above and then replace all the matches of 2nd type.

What is regex match for T1000 (T followed by any number of digits)

Comment: You request is not very good.  Can't figure out what you want, but you should not be doing this with regex.  There are much better methods using XElement or XmlElement.

Comment: @jdweng I edited and clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]** Replace with an index so..

```
    public static string ReplaceIndex(this string self, string OldString, string newString, int index)        
    {
        return self.Remove(index, OldString.Length).Insert(index, newString); 
    }
  // ...
  s = s.ReplaceIndex(m.Groups(1).Value, "newString", m.Index)
  // ...
```

**[EDIT]** Try to replace the value directly

```
// ...
s = s.Replace(m.Groups(1).Value, "newValue")
// ...
```

**[EDIT]** regex for `&*` and `&` : https://regex101.com/r/MVRS7U/1/

the generated regex function for c#

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"&\*?([^&\*\d]+)";
        string input = @"&*cool&*it's&working&in&*all&case";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

It's should be ok now :-)

__

I'm not sure about what you want exactly but here the regex for your case: https://regex101.com/r/5i3RII/1/

And here, the generated regex function for c# (you should do a custom function to fit with your need..):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"<[a-zA-Z-0-9]+\s?>([\w]+)<\/[a-zA-Z-0-9]+\s?>";
        // the example you gave
        string input = @"<T1>value1</T1>
            <T1001>value2</T1001>
            <T2000 />
            <SomeValue>value1</SomeValue >
            <A2ndValue>value2</A2ndValue >";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            // the output
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answered except the regex pattern to match is not the xml. The regex pattern I need a match for is: &*T1& or &*T1000& etc. It starts with &*T followed by any integer number and ends with &. Once the match is found, I need to extract to a string T1, T1000 etc.


In the 2nd cases, I need to match &*SomeValue&. The regex pattern can also be the same as above. And then I need to know which m.value is Type 1 (T1000) and which is Type 2 (SomeValue). this is because my code will retrieve elements of type T1000 frmom File1.xml and of type SomeValue from File2.xml.

Comment: Thanks. Your answered except the regex pattern to match is not the xml. The regex pattern I need a match for is: &*T1& or &*T1000& etc. It starts with &*T followed by any integer number and ends with &. Once the match is found, I need to extract to a string T1, T1000 etc.


In the 2nd cases, I need to match &*SomeValue&. The regex pattern can also be the same as above. And then I need to know which m.value is Type 1 (T1000) and which is Type 2 (SomeValue). This is because my code will retrieve elements of type T1000 frmom File1.xml and of type SomeValue from File2.xml.

Comment: i dont understand exactly, can you add the input and the output in your post ? i ll do it

Comment: This is the input string:
This is some text with first token &*T1& and the second token &*T1001& and more tokens &*SomeValue& and still more &*A2ndValue&.
I need to obtain the values between &* (the start) and & (the end). Then I need to know which value is like T1000 (T followed by an integer number). For this case I will retrieve the value of element T1000 in File1.xml else I will retrieve  the value of element SomeValue from File2.xml.

Comment: I clarified the question and added my code so far (with help from pirs. I get the matches I need. However how do I distinguish between the 2 Types of tokens.

Comment: i edited the question look, it should be fit with your need

Comment: The sample code in the edited question now gets the matches I need. I only need to know which of the 2 types of Tokens so I can get the replacement text from the correct xml file.

Comment: I'm not opposed for a point for the fist regex i did ;-) Else, i proprosed to replace the value with your index (new edit)

Comment: The replace will work. However once I get a match, the newvalue will be retrieved from either of 2 different  xml files. So I need a way to know which match is of the format T1000 (T followed by integer number). This way I can use an If Else construct to retrieve the replacement values from the correct xml file.

Comment: Edited with index

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to do.  Code below does everything :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\text.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "This is some text with first token &*T1& and the second token &*T1001& and more tokens &*SomeValue& and still more &*A2ndValue&.";


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            string patternToken = "&[^&]+&";
            string patternTag = @"&\*(?'tag'[^&]+)&";

            MatchCollection  matches = Regex.Matches(input, patternToken);
            foreach(Match match in matches.Cast<Match>())
            {
                string token = match.Value;
                string tag = Regex.Match(token, patternTag).Groups["tag"].Value;
                string tagValue = doc.Descendants(tag).Select(x => (string)x).FirstOrDefault();
                input = input.Replace(token, tagValue);
            }

        }
    }
}
```